# Чтение из базы SqlReader C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;
string query = string.Format("select * from Пользователи where Логин='{0}'", tBox_Login.Text);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myConnect);
sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();
if(sqlReader.Read())
{
    string password = string.Format("{0}", sqlReader["Пароль"]);
    if (password == tBox_Password.Text)
    {
        lbl_ErrorMsg("OK!", true);
        sqlReader.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_ErrorMsg("Пользователь или пароль не найден!", false);
        sqlReader.Close();
    }
    //MessageBox.Show(sqlReader["Пароль"].ToString());
}
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Пользователи](
    [Ид] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Логин] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Пароль] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Сотрудник] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Привилегии] [nchar](50) NULL
)
```

Все работает, НО в `password` у меня получается значение `"123                "`
значение в базе `"123"`

Comment: убрать пробелы можно так `password.Trim();`

Comment: @Ruslan_K, спасибо!)

Comment: @Ruslan_K овет?

Comment: `char(n) ` отличается от `varchar(n)` тем, что перый хранит данные в пуле данных, и дополняет недостающие символы пробелами, а varchar хранит данные в blob, и строка имеет именно ту длинну, которую указали при вставке.

Comment: На sql есть тоже трим `rtrim([Пароль])`.

Comment: Используйте параметрические выборки - и у вас не будет этой проблемы. Кроме того непараметрический "генерируемый" sql-код нагружает sql-сервер множеством скомпилированых выборок, что чревато сжиранием памяти на сервере и снижает быстродейсвие (под новую выборку генится новый псевдокод).

Comment: С тримом получится - если пользователся задал себе пароль `"123 "`, то аутентфикацию он не пройдёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как для начинающего такой код приемлем, но...

1. Решение 1. Лучше всего использовать параметрическую выборку (плюс не будет проблемы инжекция, и улучшится быстродействие, сократится код, сверку пароля можно возложить на сервер а не на клиент)

   ```
   using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Пользователи where Логин=@login and Пароль=@pass", myConnect)) {
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("login",tBox_Login.Text);
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass",tBox_Pass.Text);
       using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
           if (!sqlReader.Read()) {
               // Пароль не верный
           } else {
               // Пароль верный
           };
       }
   };
   ```
2. Решение 2. Можно заменить `nchar` на `nvarchar` (это может чуть замедлит но глюка не будет)
3. Решение 3. Можно в выборку добавить `select rtrim(Логин) Логин, rtrim(Пароль) Пароль` (но может возникнуть проблема с "пробелом")

P.S. sql помнит почти все выборки которые выполнялись, чем меньше выборок тем лучше. Желательно что бы вариантов выборок который пишется в CommandText было как можно меньше - тогда база будет хорошо работать.

Ещё. Часто в серьёзных организациях действует политика, что никто пароль не знает, для этого используют md5 md4 или sha шифрование. В базе хранят хеш, а админ может лишь сбросить пароль в еденицу. В mssql это звучит так `select hashbytes('md5','123')` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Надо `nchar` заменить на `nvarchar`, поскольку первый умеет хранить только строки фиксированной длины, а всё с меньшими длинами добивает пробелами.

PS: И исправь sql injection.